# Simple question about closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have two functions $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which are continuous. Now in a proof one step that is not further explained says that the set

$$M = \{x \in \mathbb{R}| f(x) \leq g(f(x))\}$$ is closed.

I thought about it but could not find a short formal argument and I fear the answer is very trivial because the book explains all others steps very detailed. I noticed that if you instead say $f(x) < g(f(x))$ it is not true anymore because you could set $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|+1}$ and $g(x)=1$ getting a contradiction for a sequence with $x_n \rightarrow 0$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: $g\circ f$ is continuous and so is $g\circ f-f$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at $h(x) = g(f(x)) - f(x)$ and observe that $M = h^{-1}[0,\infty)$ is closed because $h$ is continuous.

Comment: Rule of thumb: sets defined via $\leq$ involving continuous functions are usually closed, while sets involving $\lt$ are open.

Comment: Thanks this is the perfect explanation :-)

Comment: @Listing Let me add an (easy) exercise: if $f,g,h$ are continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, which of the following sets is closed: $\{x:f(x)g(x)\leq h(x)\}$, $\{x:\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq h(x)\}$ (if $g\neq 0$ everywhere), $\{-1\leq x\leq 1: f(x)\leq g(x)\}$, and if we have continuous functions $f_N,g_N:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for each positive integer $N$, $\{x:\text{for all positive integers }N\text{ we have } f_N(x)\leq g_N(x)\}$?

Comment: (I have included the comment above as part of a list of exercises given as an answer below.)

Comment: @Amitesh: I saw that, thanks. Already voted on it...

Answer (score 5):

Both $f$ and $g$ are continuous, so the  function $f - g\circ f$ is continuous. Hence $\{x| f(x) - g\circ f(x) \le 0\}$ is closed.

In your case, $$g(x) - g\circ f(x) = 1 = {1\over |x| + 1|} = {|x|\over |x| + 1}. $$
This is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

The following exercise might be useful. In every case, either **prove or give a counterexample**:

***Exercise 1***: If $f,g,h$ are continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, which of the following sets is closed:

**(a)** $\{x:f(x)g(x)\leq h(x)\}$,

**(b)** $\{x:\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq h(x)\}$ (if $g\neq 0$ everywhere),

**(c)** $\{-1\leq x\leq 1: f(x)\leq g(x)\}$?

***Exercise 2***: If we have continuous functions $f_N,g_N:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for each positive integer $N$, is the following set closed: $\{x:\text{for all positive integers }N\text{ we have } f_N(x)\leq g_N(x)\}$?

***Exercise 3***: If $f_N:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous for each positive integer $N$ and if $g,h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are also continuous, then is the following set closed: $\{x:\text{for some positive integer }N\text{ we have } g(x)\leq f_N(x) + h(x)\}$?

***Exercise 4***: In the notation of ***Exercise 3*** is the set $\{x:\text{for all positive integers }N\text{ we have } f_N(x)-\sin(h(x)g(x))+e^{f(x)\tan{x}}\leq g(x)\}$ closed?

***Exercise 5***: If $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous, is the set $\{x:\sin(\cos(f(x))g(x))\leq \cos(\sin(g(x))f(x))\}$ closed?

I hope this helps!

Comment: Wow thank you, I will try to solve it when tex is working again :-D

Comment: Lets start: 1. a) b) and c) are all closed using the same argument as Theo when I am not mistaken. On c) you also need that the intersection of closed sets is closed. 2. Yes because it is an intersection of closed sets which is closed.

Comment: @Listing Yes, you are correct!

Comment: (Asking and answering my own thought) For 2, it is an _infinite_ intersection of closed sets, but it doesn't matter. E.g. a boundary for an N might involve 1/N: either the intersection uses the 1/1 case or the 1/oo limit which _is_ closed in the limit. (However, a union of an infinite number of closed sets could be open.)

Comment: @Listing May I ask if you have thought about Exercises 3-5?

Comment: @Mark Hurd Yes, for example, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}]=(-1,1)$ (but you probably already know this). (@Listing: Hint for Exercise 3!)

Comment: For 3 you could set $f_N(x)=-1/N$ and $h=0$ then $M=\{x: g(x)>0\}$ which is not closed. Right? For 5 this is just a special case of my question because all mentioned functions are continuous (and composition of continuous functions is continuous). For 4 I have no idea till now.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, stupid mistake :-). I will think about 4 in a few minutes

Comment: Ok 4 is clear too, the (infinite) intersection of closed sets is closed again and for each $N$ the set is closed with a similar reasoning like in 5. :-]

Comment: @Listing: Dear Listing, yes (3), (4) and (5) are certainly correct (but I should add (the very minor point) that if $f_N=-\frac{1}{N}$ and if $h=0$, then $\{x:\text{ for some positive integer }N\text{ we have }g(x)\leq f_N(x)+h(x)\}=\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\{x:g(x)\leq -\frac{1}{N}\}=\{x:g(x)<0\}$ and not $\{x:g(x)>0\}$. It is possible that this set is closed (why?) but if you choose $g$ carefully (e.g., define $g(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$), then this set is not closed.)

Comment: Yes you can of course choose $g$ such that is still true. For example $g=0$

Comment: @Listing I forgot to refresh the page and I only saw your comments now! Indeed, my comment should appear before your comment "Oh yes ...". I removed the hint for (4). I guess I edited my comment one time too many; apologies for the confusion :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the exercises. They were very enlightening

Comment: @Listing It is my pleasure! If and when you wish, you could also look through some of my other answers where I have (almost always) provided exercises.