# Question on closed sets using a convergent sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, self-learning

**Intro**: The following two questions are from my **exam preparation sheet**, it is not mandatory and will not be accredited *(or improve marks and the like)*. There won't be a correction, merely an online solution to it. Since we had very few exercises related to the verification of open and/or closed sets, I want to ask here if my thinking and argumentation is correct. Pardon me if it happens to be a yes/no comment type of question.

**Similar**: I have read [Simple question about closed sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50086/simple-question-about-closed-sets) and found it very helpful already.

> **Problem**: Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions. Show that the set $$X_1= \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x)=g(x+(1, \dots , 1))^2 \rbrace \text{ is closed } \\ X_2= \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) > 1-g(x^2) \rbrace \text{ is open}$$

**My Approach**: For $X_1$ let $x_n$ be a sequence in $X_1$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then I have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n+(1, \dots, 1))^2 \overset{1)}{=}g(x'+(1 , \dots , 1))^2=f(x') \in X_1 $$
Is this the right approach to show that the set is closed?

 1) $g$ is continuous

---

For $X_2$ my initial thought was to come up with a contradiction, defining a convergent sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =0 \in \mathbb{R}$ which would have left to the inequality $0 > 1$ but I believe this is the wrong approach. So inspired by the linked question above I came up with: $$f(x)>1-g(x^2) \iff h(x):=f(x)+g(x^2)-1>0  \implies h(x) \in (0,\infty)$$
the defined function $h(x)$ is continuous because it's a composition of continuous functions and is an element of the open set $(0, \infty)$

Comment: correct for $X_1$. I havent read the second part yet.

Comment: correct for $X_2$. The preimage of an open set by continuous function is open.

Comment: Thanks a lot to the two of you, @MarioCarneiro, would you add that $\underline{h}^{-1}(x)=(0, \infty)$ or is there any good notation for it?

Comment: It is common to write $h^{-1}(\Bbb R^+)$ to mean the preimage of $\Bbb R^+$ by $h$, just as $h(A)$ is the image of $A$ under $h$. Here we are claiming that $X_2=h^{-1}(\Bbb R^+)$.

Comment: In the second problem, do you want the dimension $n=1$? Otherwise $f(x)$ doesn't make sense. Also, in the second part you switched $g(x^2)\mapsto g(x)^2$.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean @MarioCarneiro, I do however spot that I have made a typesetting mistake, it is supposed to be $f(x) > 1-g(x^2)$ as I have written correctly in the problem, I will correct that.

Comment: Since $f,g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, the only way $f(x)$ for $x\in\Bbb R$ makes sense (in the definition of $X_2$) is if $n=1$.

Comment: You are absolutely right about that @MarioCarneiro, they did not remark that in my problem set but evidently it must be $n=1$ such that $f,g: \mathbb{R}^1 \to \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing this answer so that the question, which was answered by the OP and in the comments, can be closed.